# RewriteRule and Hash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hash

I have a webpage which has ugly urls like this

```
DOMAINNAME/gallery.php#filter=.filtername
```

I want them to look like this

```
DOMAINNAME/artwork/filtername/
```

I've tried this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^artwork/([^.]+)/ gallery.php#filter=.$1 [NE]
```

But this doesn't do the trick. It just goes to `DOMAINNAME/artwork/`

Comment: The rewrite rule looks good. You might want to add an `L` flag and an absolute path, e.g. `RewriteRule ^artwork/([^.]+)/ /gallery.php#filter=.$1 [L,NE]`

Comment: Thanks for replying, Olaf, but I still get the same result. If I enter DOMAINNAME/artwork/misc/ in the address bar, for example, it shows me DOMAINNAME/artwork/ So it's ignoring the filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding `#` in URL then you must do a full redirect since `#` part is only interpreted in browser:

```
RewriteRule ^artwork/([^./]+)/?$ /gallery.php#filter=.$1 [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this does work, but because it's a redirect it just shows the original ugly URL, which is not what I am trying to achieve. Is there no way I can clean up the URL?

Comment: No, as I mentioned in my answer that part after `#` are not even sent to web server so even if you do an internal redirect with `#`, browser wouldn't get to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in my environment and it seems, Apache swallows everything after and including `#`, when it does an internal rewrite.This happens no matter, whether you use flag [`NE`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) or not.

So the only solution seems to be using a regular query string, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^artwork/([^.]+)/ gallery.php?filter=.$1 [L]
```

or separate the filter with a slash

```
RewriteRule ^artwork/([^.]+)/ gallery.php/filter=.$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok, looks like I'll just have to live with you. The JS I am using has the hash built into it. Changing it to a ? or / would take resources I don't have. Thanks for helping, though.

Comment: Seems, I misunderstood the question. The client sends the URL including the hash `#`? And you want to redirect to another URL, so it shows up in the browser?

Comment: I want to type, e.g., artwork/misc/ into the browser, and this gets interpreted as gallery.php#filter=.misc, but shows up as artwork/misc/

Comment: Ok, but then, why is query string not a viable solution? You could use the GET variable `filter` and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Jquery Isotope to filter and Jquery BBQ to add the hash history. Hash seems to be built into the code and I know nothing about JS so can't even consider changing it. I do know about PHP and GET but can't see how it's relevant.

Comment: Before you said, you want to enter `artwork/misc` and the server should deliver `gallery.php#filter=.misc`. So there's no JS involved, but I guess it's a bit more complicated than that.